# How to design UWP app UI?

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

I am working on a UWP app and I am new to windows 10 development. I want to create an app which will work on windows pc, mobile and tablets. In visual studio when I try to design UI for different screen sizes, UI changes happen in every other screen sizes. For example, if I made some changes in 8' screen UI then 5' mobile UI totally messes up. Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: have a look at [Adaptive Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn890382)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is a "Responsive UI design" which will automatically manipulate their properties when the screensize were triggered by the devices height or width, most of the time is the device's Width.

[Here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/01/make-your-app-look-great-on-any-size-screen-or-window-10-by-10/) is the official guide on how to do the responsive design.